# Is any way to get captcha value and store it in a variable?

Tags: selenium

I am Using Selenium RC in C# My application has 3 Captha image in Different registration pages. i have a Huge script i will run it on night hours(when i am off). Hence i feel it will be better if i can capture the last displaying captcha image value and store it in to a variable so that i can input on the relevant field. Is it Possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a hidden field (with a non-obvious name) that contains a strongly encrypted copy of the text used in the captcha then on your selenium test system decode it using the private key?

Answer (score 3):

A Captcha cannot be automated that easily. That is why they were invented!!

Alas... You can use code hackers and Image Recognition patterns and scripts. It is called OCR. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

I will not write more about this as i wont encourage others for hacking ideas. But... First: Google is your friend. Second: In my testing environment we used a captcha with a static value. And then before it went live we removed set it again for the algorithm.

Gergely.

Comment: OCR for testing purposes is WAY too unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you will need to send the captcha value in a machine readable manner, by sending it as an additional field. You would then need to remove the field after the tests are done.

Comment: Thanks Raju, But i have routine batch scripts in our production site also Eg. Need to run this script in each week schedule. its not possible for me to do that in production site.

Comment: I am not familiar with Selenium so it may sound silly, can you script Selenium so that it accepts input from a human and then runs the remaining on its own. Then someone needs to be around for entering the Captcha and then it runs unattended

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the 'input' tag with type 'hidden' in-order to handle Captcha.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
//Set the captcha values using setAttribute
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('xxxx')[0].setAttribute('value', 'xxxx')");
driver.findElement(By.name("xxxx")).sendKeys("xxxx");
```